# Android console error?

Tags: android, console

Hi now i am install android latest google sdk but if i run its take more time..At the same time console display this error...

```
[2011-05-18 16:38:26 - bgoogle] Failed to install bgoogle.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2011-05-18 16:38:26 - bgoogle] (null)
[2011-05-18 16:38:27 - bgoogle] Launch canceled!
```

Give me some link...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try resetting your adb. You can do this in following ways:

1) GOto DDMS: select "reset adb" nearby camera icon in the down arrow icon menu.

OR

2) Go to command line with platform-tools as your directory and run following commands:

i) adb kill-server
ii) adb start-server

If this doesn't work, try restarting the emulator.

Comment: I assume that you are using eclipse: Goto Eclipse >windows> Open Perspectives> Other> DDMS. If you are not using eclipse than go for options 2.

Comment: At the same time..I am using this adb kill-server. The terminal display adb: command not found

Comment: Check your command prompt, you directory must have to be: "<your android sdk location>/platform-tools". Plus you are using eclipse then you can also reset it using "DDMS".